# Showing checked checkbox rows first in the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, checkbox

I have written a code which is populating a html table using ajax call using the following code -

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "my_url",
    data: JSON.stringify(result),
    async: true,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset= Shift-JIS",
    success: function (response) {
        glResp = response;
        populateTable(glResp);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        //alert("Error!!");
    }
});
```

The data is being correctly shown on the table with a checkbox in front of each row. Now I want to show the rows which have checked checkboxes in the table first and rest of the rows after that. I have written the following code but it doesn`t seem to work. Anyone can help?

```
function populateTable(finalObject) {
    var obj = finalObject;

    var headers1 = ['Name', 'City', 'Job', 'Salary'];
    var table = $("<table id='my-table' />");
    var columns = headers1;
    columns.unshift('');
    var columnCount = columns.length;
    var row = $(table[0].insertRow(-1));

    for (var i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            var headerCell = $("<th><input type='button' id='sort'></th>");
            row.append(headerCell);
        }
        else {
            var headerCell = $("<th/>");
            headerCell.html([columns[i]]);
            row.append(headerCell);
        }
    }

    $.each(obj, function (i, obj) {
        $row = '<tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td>' + obj.Name + '</td><td>' + obj.City + '</td><td>' + obj.Job + '</td><td>' + obj.Salary + '</td></tr>';
        table.append(row);
    });

    var dvTable = $("#dvCSV");
    dvTable.html("");
    dvTable.append(table);
}

$(function () {
    $('#sort').on('click', function () {
        var newTable = $('<table class="table"></table>');
        $('.my-table').find('tr').each(function ($index, $value) {
            if ($(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked')) {
                newTable.prepend($(this));
            } else {
                newTable.append($(this));
            }
        });
        $('.table').replaceWith(newTable);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like following. Loop through all `tr` as you are doing and append the `tr` which have unchecked `checkbox` at the last of `table`.

```js
$('#dvCSV').on('click', '#sort', function () {
    $('#my-table').find('tr:not(:first)').each(function () {
        if (!$(this).find(':checkbox').is(':checked'))
            $('#my-table').append(this);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="my-table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            X
        </th>
        <th>Row Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td>Row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td>Row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td>Row 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td>Row 5</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div id="dvCSV">
    <button id="sort">Sort</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey! I tried doing this but it does not resolves the problem. I found out the problem is that the "click" event of that button in the table header isn`t getting triggered. Maybe because its appended dynamically by JS or some other reason that I am unaware of. Can you recognize why that click event isn`t getting triggered?

Comment: You need [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for dynamically generated element. See updated click event. @firstStep

Comment: Woohoo! Thanks buddy. Learnt a new thing today. It worked.
Sorry to trouble again but the append happening to the table is shifting my header row now and checked checkbox rows are appended above the header. How can i make it right?

Comment: You need to skip first row using `:not` pseudo selector like `find('tr:not(:first)')`. See updated answer. @firstStep